# Facing issue with integration of Raspberry Pi 4 I2S master to micro controller I2S slave

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, pyaudio, i2s

**I2S master:** Raspberry Pi 4 configured as detailed in https://github.com/AkiyukiOkayasu/RaspberryPi_I2S_Master/blob/master/i2smaster.dts
Using Python script created audio stream for the captured audio file and executed stream write function as detailed below,

```
form_1 = pyaudio.paInt8 #8 bit resolution
samp_rate = 44100 # 44.1KHz
chans = 1 
dev_index = 0
chunk = 4096
stream = audio.open(format = form_1,rate = samp_rate,channels = chans, \
                    input_device_index = dev_index,output = True, \
                    frames_per_buffer=chunk)                   
stream.write(frames)
```

Output signal from Raspberry Pi as observed on logic analyser: SCK=3MHz, WS=44.1KHz and data format=TDM stereo output

**I2S slave:** MCU configured as slave device (Expecting I2S format mono output with WS=187KHz). Received events on I2S slave callback, but no data received on the MCU.

Is there a way to output I2S format mono output with WS=187KHz from Raspberry Pi for the synchronization with MCU?